# Using Azure Service Bus in .Net core console app

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, servicebus

I'm trying to use Azure service bus in a .net core 2.0 console application.  I've installed the NuGet package and can see System.ServiceModel.Web in the SDK dependencies.

However when I try to add:

`using System.ServiceModel;`

I get an error stating it's not defined.

I found this tutorial online that does exactly the same:
https://www.servicebus360.com/blogs/azure-service-bus-with-dot-net-core/

What am I missing

Comment: I'm confused; the blog page you linked to doesn't seem to contain the text "System.ServiceModel" so how did you reach the conclusion that it's doing "exactly the same" as what you're doing?

Comment: Apologies, they use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, however it exhibits exactly the same problem when I try to add it

Comment: Did you check the log when you add the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget package ?

Comment: Keitn, I think you may be right - that blog has some errors. The Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace is from the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` nuget pkg, not the one they tell you to add (`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`). It also says "add `using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` to the top of your program.cs" and then posts the entire code of program.cs and it doesn't contain that line of code at all! I'd say, find another tutorial.. Or exercise some poetic license with the steps/dont follow it too closely

Comment: guys, forgot about the tutorial, that was just an example of a similar project.  The nuget package installed correctly.  It's definitely there.  I can do the same no problem when targeting .Net Framework 4.6

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I created my Net Core 2.0 console application to check this issue. As you said, the `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` is provided by Microsoft.NETCore.App as follows:

[image]

Use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and check the **Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0** under `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0`, there is no namespace for System.ServiceModel as follows:

[image]

> Using Azure Service Bus in .Net core console app

For Net Core 2.0, I have referenced [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/), and both  V 1.0.0 and V 2.0.0 could work as expected as follows:

[image]

Moreover, for .Net Framework 4.6, you could only reference Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think my confusion stemmed from using this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-relay-rest-tutorial.     Upon research I found that Service Bus WCF relay is not supported by netcore

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no easy way to write a WCF service with .NET Core for now, while you could call WCF service from your .NET Core client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to get a .net core 2.0 console app working like from the blog [described above][1]
https://www.servicebus360.com/blogs/azure-service-bus-with-dot-net-core/

You need to use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget

I particularly liked his blog due to setting up the service bus via azure and instructions to newbies in the pub/sub architecture.